# How to delete a column in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get the right logic, this is what i tried:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button id="addTd" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        Add Column
      </button>
      <button id="addTr" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        Add Row
      </button>
      <table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td data-td-index="1"><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Label" name="Name" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn">-</button></td>
            <td data-td-index="2"><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Label" name="Name" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn">-</button></td>
            <td data-td-index="3"><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Label" name="Name" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn">-</button></td>
            <td data-td-index="4"><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Label" name="Name" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn">-</button></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="tr_clone" data-row-index="1">
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeRow">-</button></td>
            <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="who" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="data" name="location" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I do the following to add rows and columns and remove rows

```
$("#addTr").on('click', function() {
    var i = 0;
    var $tr    = $('tbody tr[data-row-index="1"]');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
    $("tbody tr").each(function(){
        i++;
        $(this).attr("data-row-index", i);
    });
});

$("#addTd").on("click", function(){
  $("thead tr").append('<td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Label" name="Name" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary removeColumn">-</button></td>');
  $("tbody tr").append('</td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="data" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>');
  var i = 0;
  $(document).find("thead td").each(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).attr("data-td-index", i);
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$(document).on("click", ".removeColumn", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

But I can't get the logic of how I could delete a column, I've manage to delete a row tho.

[Here it is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwmpN/578/) to play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the index of the cell the button click occurs in and delete all cells in the table having the same index.

e.g.

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeColumn", function(){
  var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
  $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by column number?

```
var colnum = $(e.target).closest("td").length;
$(e.target).closest("table").find("tr").each(function(){ 
$(this).find("td:eq(" + colnum + ")").remove()});
```

Comment: Place it inside removeColumn click function.